# JavaScript problem with removing a new element that I added

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and am trying to avoid tutorials and guides as much as I can but I'm stuck. I have a tasklist I'm working on. Currently, I can add a new task. Initially I had hard-coded a few starting tasks, Each task that's been hard-coded can be closed(hidden). When I add a new task to the list it is given a close button like the existing tasks, it has the same class as them as well, but will not close. I'm not sure what to do at this point since the new tasks looks like the existing as far as structure and class names but the JavaScript doesn't work on these newly added elements. Here's my code

html:

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="form">
            <h2>Tasks to do today: <span id="today"></span>  </h2>
            <div class="form-control">
              
                <input type="text" id="addTask" placeholder="Add task">
                <span onclick="addElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>                     
        </form>   
        <ul class="taskList" id="taskList">
            <li class="taskItem">item1</li>
            <li class="taskItem">item2</li>
            <li class="taskItem">item3</li>
            <li class="taskItem">item4</li>
        </ul>     
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addClose() {
    const nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("taskItem");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    const span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    const txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    nodeList[i].appendChild(span);
    }
}

function closeTask() {
    const close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() { 
            const div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function addElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("addTask").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    li.classList.add("taskItem")
    if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("taskList").appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById("addTask").value = "";
  
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    li.appendChild(span);
  
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

// Run Functions
addClose();
closeTask();
```

Comment: What is `close` in `addElement`?

Comment: it's a class name to be added to the span inside the new li thats being created

Comment: I mean, the variable `close`. In other functions, you declare and define `const close = ...`. If there is no variable `close` in outer scope, `close.length` inside `addElement` will break your code.

Comment: yep, thats it thanks!